# How does the d3.quantile function work?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I'm looking at the source code for d3's quantile scales. In the rescale function there is a call to a d3.quantile function.

The call looks like this

```
  function rescale() {
    var k = 0,
        q = range.length;
    thresholds = [];
    while (++k < q) thresholds[k - 1] = d3.quantile(domain, k / q);
    return scale;
  }
```

The function looks like this

```
d3.quantile = function(values, p) {
  var H = (values.length - 1) * p + 1,
      h = Math.floor(H),
      v = +values[h - 1],
      e = H - h;
  return e ? v + e * (values[h] - v) : v;
};
```

Why does the d3.quantile function give us well formed (and by this I mean integer) bins with a reasonable and consistent bin size?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Could you illustrate with an example please?

Comment: Basically - why does the d3.quantile function work and why is it used in generating quantiles by d3?

Comment: "Why does it work" is a very broad and not well-defined question. "Why is it used" -- I don't know, because it's there?